# Linking video to GPS trail?

Tags: gps, software-recommendations, video

Does anyone know of a program, extension or tool that links a video with a GPS trail?

I found this video and would like to be able to do something similar.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G07DWVRJBVU

Comment: AtlasRider has several GPS/Youtube Geotagged Videos example http://www.atlasrider.com/?p=301

Answer (score 3):

If you work with [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/), you can use the [plugin eVis](http://biodiversityinformatics.amnh.org/open_source/evis/) to link your data with external files. It has been developed for pictures but I assume that it can work as well for videos.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind tweaking a little HTML/JavaScript I found an [example](http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.com/2009/04/you-tube-and-google-earth.html) of using the [Google Earth](https://developers.google.com/earth/) and [YouTube player](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#player_apis) APIs in conjunction to do something like this.

Basically you would create a [Google Earth tour from your GPS track](http://support.google.com/earth/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183681) and save it as a KML file, upload the video to YouTube, and tweak the code to point to them.

The APIs may have changed slightly since this was created, and the videos don't seem to play on their own like the instructions suggest, but it might be fun to play with.

Answer (score 0):

[This is built in to ArcGIS 10.0](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005z00000024000000.htm), you just need to [time-enable a layer in your Table of Contents](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/About_enabling_time_on_data/005z0000000p000000/).

> You can export your time visualization to Audio Video Interleaved
>   (.avi) or QuickTime (.mov) video files.

Comment: Will a time-enabled layer play a video, like the one from the car in the above youtube video? I would like to simultaneously see the time enable GPS track and a video of what you would see if you walked the GPS track.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out the Android App "GeoCam" (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myway&hl=en), it takes videos in GeoVid format. There is a possibility to upload the files to http://www.geovid.org/ and share them with the world.  Maybe some day there will be more video players or GIS plugins for displaying geovids.