# How to imbed lat/long geodata into GoPro 4K video

Tags: data, video

I'm looking for an efficient way to take 360 panorama video and imbed geodata lat/long into the video.

I'd prefer to mount something like this http://www.360heros.com/ on a truck and drive down a neighborhood and overlay geodata on the video itself.

For example, If I drive down the street, I want the street numbers to be overlaid on the homes that I view on the video as I drive by.

I'm trying to find something that is off the shelf that I can buy that will associate my video with accurate geodata.

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you're after. A camera that has GPS? A way to associate a GIS or GPS created coordinate/line/track with the video? We have a few questions on the subject: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21588/ and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20643/ You need to have a location information stream and video stream that can be linked, be it by timecode or reference points or whatever (there's another question with a long comment discussion on this here somewhere). You might also Google "georeference video".

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, since GoPro has no built-in GPS sensor. But you might, however, look after Sony HDR action cams or classic dashcams having GPS sensor built-in.